# AMD Opteron 248 H264

Tags: h.264, cpu-speed

Would an AMD Opteron 248 CPU machine handle slightly faster than real time H264 encoding, using something like Sorenson Squeeze 8?

Comment: I doubt you would achieve real time H264 encoding on any CPU. It really depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: Slightly faster than what?

Comment: @music2myear "slightly faster than real time"

Comment: @slhck: It's entirely possible to do real-time (or faster) h.264 encoding on CPUs, even at decent resolutions.  The OP's particular CPU?  Only at MMS-sized videos.  *Maybe* single pass low-quality SD.  Definitely not high quality SD or HD resolutions.

Comment: @afrazier Yeah, that's what I meant with, "it depends" :) I could have been more precise. Thanks for the addendum.

Comment: Thanks @afrazier - I didn't think the 248 would be able to cope (would be transcoding 576i MPEG2 to 2mbit H264).